# Protect folder with .htaccess but access it from successful PHP login

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried and tried, fiddled with `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`
But cannot seem to get it right.

I need to have a folder with its contents protected from the external world
but when someone logins successfully in my PHP user/pass page, then
it would redirect it to this protected folder and open the `index.php` inside it.

One solution would be inserting **manually** in the beginning of the index.php from the protected folder a check for `_SESSION['is_logged_in']==1` but I would want to make the whole process cleaner.

Is there a way I can protect this folder with `.htaccess` and then, once a login is successful in the main login page it would redirect and allow access to display the contents of the passworded folder?

I hope I described as clear as possible what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: I think its will be better if you put an index.php in your folder and check session there on first place.

Comment: The thing is that the folder contains an index.php or an index.html + other files. So it's rather messy, although my first choice too...

Comment: In this situation you need to create a script which will check credential first and later allow access eg.
**<a href='checkauth.php?content=yourcontent.html'>yourcontent</a>**